# OpenGL Move One Of My Two Shapes

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, sdl-2

I'm creating a game in SDL where everything has to be drawn in OpenGL. I've drawn two shapes with different textures and added keyboard controls. My problem is only my Player textured shape should be controllable but instead both of my shapes are stuck together and the vector I thought controlled the enemy position doesn't. Is my problem when I draw? How do I make it so I my player controls only move the player shape.

```
//Declare transform and model matrix.
    glm::mat4 Model;  glm::mat4 Rotation; glm::mat4 View;
    glm::mat4 Projection;

    glm::vec3 Player = glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.5f, -1.0f);
    GLfloat playermovespeed = 0.1f;

    Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, -1.0f, 100.0f);

    Model = glm::translate(Model, Player);
    GLint ProjectionLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ProjectionMat");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Projection));

    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    while (WindowOpen)
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
        Model = glm::mat4();
        Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 15.0f, 5.0f)); //Position of enemy shape
        GLint ModelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ModelMat");
        GLint ViewLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ViewMat");
        //glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model*Rotation));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        //Player texture
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
        Model = glm::mat4();                         //y
        Model = glm::translate(Model, Player); //Position control of ship.
        ModelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ModelMat");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(View));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                WindowOpen = false;
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    Player.x += playermovespeed;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    Player.x -= playermovespeed;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But just in case here is also how I set up everything.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,   // Top Right
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,   // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {   start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,   
        1, 2, 3,
    };

//Load image Enemy; //Load image Player; //Load shaders;

GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    GLuint EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    GLuint texture[2];
    glGenTextures(2, texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    //set texture parameters. First texture.

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    //Second texture same way as first; //Set texture parameters

    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Why is this line commented out? `//glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model*Rotation));` and what is Rotation?

Comment: I'm just gonna go on a limb here and say uncomment that line and remove the rotation bit so it's just `glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model));`

Comment: You must set `ModelMat` to different matrices for both draw calls. And I don't see you setting it at all (except commented line)